# On what side is 'HTTP Error 403: request disallowed by robots.txt' generated?

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying out Mechanize to make some routine simpler. I have managed to bypass that error by using `br.set_handle_robots(False)`. There are talks about how ethical it's to use it. What I wonder about is where this error is generated, on my side, or on server side? I mean does Mechanize throw the exception when it sees some `robots.txt` rule or does server decline the request when it detects that I use an automation tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server detects the user-agent. If the user agent match one in robots.txt, the rules are applied by the client.
By default, mechanize returns "Python-urllib/2.7".

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Answer (score 0):

The server blocks your activity with such response.

Is it your site? If not, follow the rules:

1. Obey `robots.txt` file
2. Put a delay between request, even if `robots.txt` doesn't require it.
3. Provide some contact information (e-mail or page URL) in the User-Agent header.

Otherwise be ready site owner blocking you based on User-Agent, IP or other information he thinks distinguish you from legitimate users.

Comment: The site I am trying to mechanize is blocking me from viewing robots.txt, whats the meaning of this. Does this means no bots are allowed to it?